# Proof of return ticket at Immigration

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, cancellations, expedia

I am looking to purchase a flight ticket to show as a proof of return ticket at immigration. I am not sure about my return dates so I can't actually commit to a date.

I explored dummy ticket options where many websites give you a temporary ticket with valid PNR which can be verified on the airline's website for couple of days however this is too sketchy for me.

I also came across this rule of 24 hour free cancellation for all flights in USA. I am looking to book a flight from London to Delhi.

My questions are:

1. would this flight be eligible for 24 hour free cancellation? I doubt it as the flight does not originate or end in US soil.
2. However, I came across this [article](https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/book-flight-tickets-with-24-hour-free-cancellation-on-expedia/) from a prominet Digital Nomad which mentions that we can use [Expedia](https://www.expedia.com/) to book the LHR to DEL flight and it would still be eligible for 24 hour free cancellation. I even verified it myself by filling out the required details and it showed me a message of 24 hour free cancellation period. Should I choose this option?
3. Many airlines like British Airways, Qatar Airways etc. provide an option to hold the fare for a minimal fee for 24-48 hours. I want to know if I choose this option then would I get a valid PNR right away or it would only be generated once I actually pay the entire amount?

Comment: You donthave to commit to a date, but you do hve to commit to having a return ticket - get an open one or one which can be easily changed.  Trying to game UK immigration is just going to end up with a bad outcome, so dont even try it.  Buy the return ticket.  The reason Immigration wants you to have one is so you can leave the country - if you dont have one and run out of funds, you cant then leave and thus become an illegal overstayer, so they want you to have a guaranteed ticket already.  And yes, they do check.

Comment: @Moo exactly I dont want to "game" the UK immigration at all, I guess if I have to actually buy a ticket then I might take the Expedia option, in worst case, I will have the ticket, in best case, I would be able to cancel it after clearing immigration.

Comment: But that *is* gaming UK immigration - they want you to have a return ticket because that gives you a way out of the country, while you dont want a ticket for longer than to prove you have one on entry to the country.  Thats gaming the system.  And if immigration finds out, they will view you with suspicion.

Comment: @Moo how is this "gaming" the immigration, I would have an actual fully paid ticket when I encounter immigration. I will leave UK before the date I mentioned in my UK VISA application. By your logic, any modification/cancellation after clearing immigration is "gaming" them which I dont agree with.

Comment: As I say above, theres a specific reason UK Immigration want you to have a return ticket - you only want to fulfil the requirement at face value, to specifically secure entry into the country, and then you want to get your money back.  Thats gaming the system.  And yes, UK immigration does see things like extending your stay and other things after you have secured entry also as gaming the system, and it calls into doubt your credulity on your next entry attempt.  UK Immigration are not stupid, dont treat them like you think they are.

Comment: @Moo As I mentioned, I would not be extending the stay, I would leave the UK days before what I mentioned in the Visa form. Your point is valid if someone intentionally wants to extend the stay by just fulfilling the requirement of having a return ticket. Tbh, it the UK immigration who treat us as stupid, there is no legal requirement of having a return ticket + I have literally applied for a visa where UKVI has verified and "assured" themselves that this person has enough funds and reason to leave the UK.

Comment: And what are your plans should the air fare double or triple for your return journey and you cant afford it?  Thats why Immigration wants you to have a valid ticket.  I never said anything about you extending your stay, that was in response to a comment you made about changes - the requirement for a valid ticket is for many reasons.  Funds available at visa issuing time can be spent or otherwise become unavailable.

Comment: @Moo what if you get covid/some other illness and can't travel on your dates and now you have to extend the stay and you can't afford the double/triple fare...

I would get a clear idea about my return dates after 1-2 days of landing in UK, UKVI should have enough "trust" on their skills on which they have issued a visa to a person after calculation all possibilities of why this person would not leave UK.

Comment: Exceptional circumstances are taken into consideration - your situation is not exceptional.  In fact, your situation is mundane and not comparable to your example.  Buy the ticket, dont mess around trying to get around the requirement with pathetic justifications.

Answer (score 1):

I just cleared the immigration at Gatwick airport.

I chose the Expedia option with 24h cancellation. I cancelled the ticket right after I cleared the immigration.

I will now rebook my return ticket in couple of days. I will return to India before the date mentioned in the visa form.